# In SQL(Ms-Access) how to Order By customized order?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-order-by

This question is derived from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34690526/2144390)

Please refer to it for the context.

Basically I would like to use below SQL query to retrieve a list of records:

```
Select * From [TableA] Where [A_Design] In ("A", "D", "C" , "B")
```

As far as I know, "In" clause will not guarantee the retrieved record will follow the same order as ("A", "D", "C" , "B").

My question is how can we achieve this target? Or is it possible if the list is a dynamically generated long list?

---

Thanks to Gordon Linoff, problem solved! Below is the working solution modified from his example:

```
select instr(",A,D,C,B,", "," & [A_Design] & ",")
from [TableA]
where [A_Design] In ("A", "D", "C" , "B")
order by 1;
```

Many thanks to Luis Siquot also, your solution also works, but comparing with Instr() method, codes are little bit longer.

Comment: You can use `...in ('a') union .... in ('d') union ...`

Comment: Hi artm, thanks for your quick response, can you elaborate more on your answer, it would be better if you can give some example codes.

Comment: @artm Query results have no guaranteed order except as imposed by an ORDER BY.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/396748/3404097) including [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/397259/3404097).

Comment: @philipxy  Thanks, problem was solved basing on Gordon Linoff's example.   But still thank you for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a bunch of nested `iif()` statements.  An alternative is to use `instr()`:

```
select *
from TableA
where [A_Design] In ("A", "D", "C" , "B")
order by instr("ADCB", A_Design);
```

Note:  this works fine for single character codes.  For longer codes, you should use delimiters:

```
select *
from TableA
where [A_Design] In ("A", "D", "C" , "B")
order by instr(",A,D,C,B,", "," & A_Design & ",");
```

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, "Instr" is a very creative idea, I never thought in that direction, I will try it and feedback soon. iif() for long list could be quite messy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, the Instr() method works. But the code can not be put after "Order By", must put after "select", then "order by 1".  I have revised my question to include your example. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use swich in your order by clause as shown here

```
Select * From [TableA] Where [A_Design] In ("A", "D", "C" , "B")
order by switch(
     A_Design ="A", 1,
     A_Design ="D", 2,
     A_Design ="C", 3,
     A_Design ="B", 4
)
```

Swich is the equivalent of standard `case when`

Comment: Luis Siquot, I think switch() will also work for my case, but the codes will be little longer than the "Instr()" solution. Thank you very much for your prompt response.